# How to Disable the output of command in php

Tags: php, linux, command, output

```
system("echo $new_password | sudo -u root passwd --stdin $username");
```

I am using this code to change the password in PHP. But it shows the following output on webpage:

```
Changing password for user abcd@xyz.com. passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
```

How can I disable this output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also just redirect it

```
system("echo $new_password | sudo -u root passwd --stdin $username") 3>/dev/null
```

This sends stdout to null.  Though if anything is coming in through a different way (e.g. stderr), you'd have to redirect that separately.

Answer (score 0):

use exec instead of system

```
<?php
 exec("echo $new_password | sudo -u root passwd --stdin $username");
?>
```